# Changelistener not triggered in Console but by GUI

Tags: java, task, command-line-interface, listener

I have a Task which should be runnable and updateable on Console and GUI. Consider my Task written as

```
public static Task<Void> doStuff() {
    Task<Void> task;
    task = new Task<Void>() {
        final int totalSteps = 4;
        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            
            updateProgress(0, totalSteps);
            updateMessage("1");
            action(1);
            updateProgress(0, totalSteps);
            updateMessage("2");
            action(2);
            //etc..
            return null;
        }
    };
    new Thread(task)
            .start();
    return task;
}
```

With bonding the Progress and Message Property within my JavaFX GUI, everything works as expected and the GUI gets updated according to the Progress.
Within my CLI, I tried to build a simple Progress Bar which updates the User about the Operation Progress

```
private static void progressBar(Task task) {
    
    task.progressProperty().addListener((new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
            // Return to line beginning
            System.out.print("\r");
            int percentage = (int) (100 * task.progressProperty().get());
            System.out.format("[%3d%%] %s", percentage, task.messageProperty().get());
            
            if (percentage == 100) {
                System.out.println("Finished");
            }
        }
    }));
    
}
}
```

As far as I could see with debugging, the Change Listeners changed Method will not get triggered. What did I set up wrong about it? Even the Finished Print at the End will not get written.

Comment: How do you run the CLI example? The `Task` class is designed to work with the FX thread, so I suspect it may not even emit progress updates and messages if the JavaFX infrastructure was not initialized, as there will be no FX UI thread...

Comment: The CLI is started in a Main Class as Standart Java. I tried to Invoke the Progress Bar within a Thread too, but this did not work eitherways. So would i have to invoke the CLI as a JavaFX Thread? Would this even be possible in a not GUI-able Environment?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will be possible, but it probably won't be desirable even if it was. Maybe you should consider not using `Task` if you need a solution to work without JavaFX, as `Task` seems to tightly connected to JavaFX.

Comment: Well, then i would Need a threading construct wich is egible to work with JavaFX, as the GUI should stay updateable. But i counterchecked, you are right. I did put a print at the end of the Task and it will not get executed

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, updates to the properties in a JavaFX `Task` are performed on the FX Application Thread. That thread is the thread used to render the JavaFX Scene graph and is started by the JavaFX toolkit when it is launched. If the JavaFX toolkit is not running, then the thread won't be started and those properties will not be updated.

If you want something that can be run in a background that needs to be functional outside of a JavaFX application, then you should use threading facilities that are not dependent on JavaFX. In this case you can simply implement `Runnable` or `Callable`. If you want to provide notifications when state changes, create a callback, to be called when the state changes. Callbacks are best represented using interfaces from the `java.util.function` package.

In the case you show, it looks like you only really need the message and progress together, so you could probably use a `BiConsumer<String, Integer>`.

```
public class DoStuff implements Runnable {

    private final int totalSteps ;
    private BiConsumer<String, Integer> update ;

    public DoStuff(int totalSteps) {
        this.totalSteps = totalSteps ;
    }

    public void setUpdate(BiConsumer<String Integer> update) {
        this.update = update ;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (update != null) {
            update.accept("0", 0) ;
        }
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= totalSteps ; i++) {
            action(i);
            if (update != null) {
                update.accept(Integer.toString(i), i);
            }
        }
    }

    private void action(int i) {
        // ...
    }

    public int getTotalSteps() {
        return totalSteps() ;
    }
}
```

and now you would do

```
public void progressBar(DoStuff doStuff) {
    doStuff.setUpdate((s, p) -> {

        // Return to line beginning
        System.out.print("\r");
        int percentage = 100 * p / doStuff.getTotalSteps();
        System.out.format("[%3d%%] %s", percentage, s);

        if (percentage == 100) {
            System.out.println("Finished");
        }
    });
}
```

And you execute this in a background thread with

```
new Thread(doStuff).start();
```

If you wanted to use this in a JavaFX environment, you can, but make sure your callback updates any UI components on the FX Application Thread:

```
DoStuff doStuff = ... ;
doStuff.setUpdate((s, p) -> Platform.runLater(() -> {
    label.setText(s);
    double progress = 1.0 * p / doStuff.getTotalSteps();
    progressBar.setProgress(p);
}));
```

It's also reasonably easy to create a `Task<Void>` that wraps this, and exposes the progress and message in the usual JavaFX way:

```
DoStuff doStuff = ... ;
Task<Void> doStuffTask = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void call() {
        doStuff.setUpdate((s, p) -> {
            updateProgress(p, doStuff.getTotalSteps());
            updateMessage(s);
        });
        doStuff.run();
        return null ;
    }
};
```

Then do

```
progressBar.progressProperty().bind(doStuffTask.progressProperty());
label.textProperty().bind(doStuffTask.messageProperty());

Thread t = new Thread(doStuffTask);
t.setDaemon(true);
t.start();
```

as usual.